# R Shiny vertical slider but mouse dragging horizontally

Tags: css, r, shiny, rotation

I've come across some open issues when looking for a way to make a vertical slider in R Shiny apps, to put next to one of my plots so that the user can "move a horizontal line" in the plot with a slider that follows the same range as the plot's y axis.

I managed to make the slider turn vertical, but it still wants the mouse to be dragged horizontal. Anyone a clue how to attack this with css to rotate the drag action?

```
      library(shiny)

  ui  <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(3, 
 sliderInput(inputId = 'myslider1', label = 'Change vertical', min = -5, max = 6.3, step = 0.1, value = -6)
    ),
  column(3, 
     sliderInput(inputId = 'myslider2', label = 'Change horizontal', min = -5, max = 6.3, step = 0.1, value = 0)
  ), style = "margin-top:200px"
  ),

  tags$style(HTML(".js-irs-0 {  transform: rotateZ(270deg)}")),

  tags$style(HTML(".js-irs-0 .irs-bar-edge, .js-irs-0 .irs-bar {background: yellow}"))

  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) { 


  }


  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Maybe try to mess with `.irs-slider single`

Comment: I tried, things like tags$style(HTML(".js-irs-0 .irs-slider single {transform: rotate(270deg)}"))  and various others but no luck

Answer (score 1):

There is this function `noUiSliderInput()`  from the [shinyWidgets](https://rdrr.io/github/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/man/noUiSliderInput.html) package that does what you need.

See example below:

```
if (interactive()) {

### examples ----

# see ?demoNoUiSlider
demoNoUiSlider("more")


###  basic usage ----

library( shiny )
library( shinyWidgets )


ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$br(),

  noUiSliderInput(
    inputId = "noui1",
    min = 0, max = 100,
    value = 20
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res1"),

  tags$br(),

  noUiSliderInput(
    inputId = "noui2", label = "Slider vertical:",
    min = 0, max = 1000, step = 50,
    value = c(100, 400), margin = 100,
    orientation = "vertical",
    width = "100px", height = "300px"
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res2")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$res1 <- renderPrint(input$noui1)
  output$res2 <- renderPrint(input$noui2)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)

}
```